# Bash script unexpectedly stops executing (used to to work)

Tags: bash, grep

I've been using this script I wrote (augmented from [here](http://blog.gonzih.me/blog/2012/02/17/how-to-use-magnet-links-with-rtorrent/)) for a couple years to open torrent links from the web browser.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /rtorrent_watch
[[ "$1" =~ xt=urn:btih:([^&/]+) ]] || exit;
echo "d10:magnet-uri${#1}:${1}e" > "meta-${BASH_REMATCH[1]}.torrent"

if [ "$(pgrep -c "rtorrent")" = "0" ]; then
    gnome-terminal --geometry=105x24 -e rtorrent
fi
```

Suddenly one day it stopped working. The first part still works--it saves a torrent file--but the if statement doesn't execute. If I change the condition to 0 == 0 it works, but then it starts rtorrent even if it's already running. If I do

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /rtorrent_watch
[[ "$1" =~ xt=urn:btih:([^&/]+) ]] || exit;
echo "d10:magnet-uri${#1}:${1}e" > "meta-${BASH_REMATCH[1]}.torrent"

if ! pgrep "rtorrent" > dev/null; then
    gnome-terminal --geometry=105x24 -e rtorrent
fi
```

Which should be equivalent as the first one, it also doesn't work. If I make a script with only the if statement, it works correctly. Is there some reason pgrep can't be executed in this situation?

Thanks!

Edit:

```
$ pgrep -c "rtorrent" | xxd # when rtorrent is not running
00000000: 300a                                     0.
$ pgrep -c "rtorrent" | xxd # when rtorrent is running
00000000: 310a                                     1.
```

Comment: Please specify the output of `pgrep -c "rtorrent" | xxd`.
Normally, newlines don't cause problems with that sort of code, but maybe `bash` or `pgrep` decided to play strict. It could be a newline problem.

Comment: It did print newlines, but I replaced the condition with `"$(pgrep -c "rtorrent" | tr -d '\n')" = "0"` and it still fails.

Comment: Did you ever try to make sure that rtorrent is currently not running and run just `if ! pgrep "rtorrent" > dev/null && gnome-terminal --geometry=105x24 -e rtorrent` manually? If that spawns a new terminal with rtorrent, than you should probably not worry about that part of your script. More likely the regular expression is failing. Replace that part with `[[ "$1" =~ xt=urn:btih:([^&/]+) ]] || { echo "regex match failed"; exit; }`.

If that turns up something interesting, your expression isn't matching anymore.

Comment: No, it's definitely the if statement condition. The regex works because it saves a torrent file correctly and, like I wrote, if I make the condition something like 0 = 0, it executes every time. Also, if I echo something after the regex it does print. Both halves of the script work perfectly on their own as separate scripts, it's just when assembled that the if condition no longer evaluates as true.

Answer (score 2):

No,

```
if [ $(pgrep -c rtorrent) == 0 ]
```

and

```
if ! pgrep "rtorrent" /dev/null
```

are by no means "equivalent".

The first is - wrongly - comparing `pgrep`s **standard output** to 0, while the latter checks if `pgrep "rtorrent" /dev/null` returned a value (i.e., return value, totally disregarding any **output**) other than `0` (which typically means "success".)

Note that `pgrep` will bail out due to giving it two parameters - `"rtorrent"` and `/dev/null`. You probably meant to execute

```
if ! pgrep "rtorrent" >/dev/null
```

or even

```
if ! pgrep "rtorrent" >/dev/null 2>&1
```

to also redirect `stderr`.

---

Also note, that the `test` utility, which is invoked when you call `[`, does not know an `==` operator, c.f. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html.

Instead, use the `=` operator, or switch to `bash`s non-portable `[[` built-in.

If relying on any output, it is advisable to quote the subshell call and the pattern you want to match against, like so:

```
if [ "$(pgrep -c "rtorrent")" = "0" ];
```

If this is still not doing what you want to have it do, take a look at the output of `pgrep -c "rtorrent"`.

Comment: You're right that I mistyped
    if ! pgrep "rtorrent" >/dev/null
in the question.
And I was not aware that == didn't work with the [ command.
I've replaced it with the corrected
    if [ "$(pgrep -c "rtorrent")" = "0" ];
and it still doesn't work (in this script).
    pgrep -c "rtorrent"
indeed returns "0" when rtorrent isn't running and "1" when it is.